# Включение исходных файлов в Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

не так давно пользуюсь CMake и вот наткнулся на такую, нельзя сказать проблему, а скорее не понятную мне вещь, пример:

```
...   

set (NETWORK_PATH Network)
set (NETWORK ${NETWORK_PATH}/IServer.h
             ${NETWORK_PATH}/Server.h
             ${NETWORK_PATH}/Server.cpp
             ${NETWORK_PATH}/Client.h
             ${NETWORK_PATH}/Client.cpp)

...

set (SOURCES main.cpp ${DATA_OBJECTS} ${EXCEPTIONS} ${NETWORK} ${UTILS} ${SYSTEM_CHECKING})

...

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

...
```

Как видно из этого примера я разбиваю в Cmake все на каталоги потом собираю все в переменной SOURCES и уже после этого отдаю на линковку к исполняемому файлу. Вопрос заключается в следующем... Нельзя ли как-то автоматически включать файлы ну к примеру там скан пакетов как в Java с использованием Maven? Потому что такое подход, который сейчас использую я, немного утомляет... приходится каждый файл удалять и добавлть в ручную...

Answer (score 0):

Для начала: зачем вы в одной папке держите хэдэры и соурсные файлы? Это лучше разделять. Когда у вас все хэдэры в отдельной папке `include`, то в `CMakeLists.txt` их можно включить с помощью:

```
include_directories(include)
```

Далее, когда у вас все соурсные файлы в отдельной папке, к примеру `sources`, то делаем так:

```
set(GLOB SRC_SRC "sources/*.cpp")
```

Поясню: сдесь в SRC_SRC включаются все файлы с расширением .cpp которые есть в папке sources. Далее просто делаете:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_SRC})
```

Как-то так. Но вообще лучше делать библиотеки, конечно.

Comment: Пояните, пожалуйста, за что минусы?

Comment: Вместо команды set(GLOB...) необходимо использовать file(GLOB...)